restoration of motion pictures
A motion picture as The Alamo 70mm this was only produced on a old Laser disc many years ago and no longer sold as a new item : the quality as only that of old crt tv sets not Digital
WE have restored the video  quality and sound to Both Blu-ray and 4K quality and made a 3D bluray movie from it as well   three seperate new products
this entailed huge changes for the original but not changing the content of the original
in fact just making a new product
we omitted to include the trade mark that was on the original
My question is as its a new product how can we protect our restoration so as to sell it on the open market

as the changes are extensive and include the final method of production from a laser that's no longer available to digital Disc surly that under Australian trade laws makes it a new product.

years ago millions of VHS tapes remade colorization  were sold retail and still available not one authorised by the copyright owner  all sold as New products

It is not a question of effort or technology, it is one of time. For very old movies, copyright has expired. For newer ones, not. For each example, consult a lawyer. If your technical work is so great, surely you have budget for that as well.

As most legislations see it, you have not produced a new product. You must have a license from the original copyright holder and your product would include information that you have the license. Then you can sue anybody who pirates your work.
You write "we have" rather than "we want to" and from your user name you seem to want to go commercial with your line of work. Your business plan really needs to budget for specialist lawyers, just as you need to budget the technical work.

read "pirates your work" as "Pirates your new contribution to the work, in case the copyright has lapsed on the original". In case nothing was added, there has been no new contribution and there is nothing that could be pirated.

@Trish, The Alamo with John Wayne would still be in copyright.

in that case it is to be read "Pirates for the remainder of the original copyright in Australia" - which would be dictated by australian copyright law, and would be 2030, as films prior to 1969 only get 70 years from publication. Only for the US it is 1960+95.
